# How to fix this flexbox alignment issue due to unsupported 'flex-grow' in IE10?

Tags: css, less, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

Here is the HTML markup

```
<div class='container'>
  <li class="options list-unstyled">
    <div class="rank-label">
      <span class="rank theme-inverse-color">1</span>
      <span class="name">AAAAA</span>
      <div class="move-btns">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-up"><span class="icon icon-down">Down</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-down"><span class="icon icon-up">Up</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

And here is the less (css) code

```
.square (@size) {
  width: @size;
  height: @size;
}

.options {
  li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.options {
  font-size: 30px;
}


.text {
  .flex-grow(1);
  .align-items(center);
  .justify-content(center);
}

.inverse-color {
  color: blue;
}

.rank {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  .align-items(center);
  .justify-content(center);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  .square(40px);
  min-width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.rank-label {
  .display(flex);
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.name {
  .display(flex);
  .flex-grow(1);
  .align-items(center);
  padding-right: 30px;
  min-height: 35px;
}

.move-btns {
  .display(flex);
  .flex-basis(auto);
  .flex-shrink(0);
  .flex-grow(0);
  .justify-content(center);
}
```

So in browsers like chrome, Safari and IE11, the output looks exactly like I expected:

[image]

However in IE10, the alignment is off. It has somehow become:

[image]

the number and text 'AAAAA' are all shifted to right-hand side.

I have tried tweaking `flex-grow` and other parameters but they have no effect.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is a link to the code in codepen.io: http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/bpygoV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @orangeh0g 's answer, I checked the css generated by autoprefixer in my codepen code. I find that I only need to add

```
 -ms-flex-positive: 1;
```

to the `text` css class and the misalignment will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to do is turn on the autoprefixer in your code pen css settings and it will start working.  Basically E10 runs on the old version of the flexbox syntax.  So it needs the vendor prefixes.  Good Luck.

Comment: His codepen code is fully prefixed (see compiled version).

Comment: Hi orangeh0g, @Michael_B is right. I am using this github project https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codio/Flex.less/master/flex.less to autoprefix

Comment: My mistake...I see that the flex syntax was using vendor prefixes...based on the flex.less file included.  When I just use that and test in IE10 I see the same reported issue.  However when I turn on AutoPrefixing also the issue goes away and behaves as expected in IE10

Comment: I would add that the flex.less file you are including is about one year old and could be outdated. AutoPrefixer will work in replacement of that file.

Comment: @orangeh0g Is this https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer the autoprefixer you are referring to?

Comment: That certainly seems to be the main autoprefixer folks are using however I was just taking about the one that is included in code pen settins on the css tab.